# ganache extract logs from reverted transaction?

Tags: ganache, logs

Is it possible to extract logs from reverted transactions in Ganache?

Of course, the public blockchain won't keep logs for reverted transactions.

However, I'm wondering is there a way in ganache (local blockchain) to find out what the logs would have been for a transaction if it hadn't reverted it, that is, the logs that occurred up until the point of reverting?

I am using a ganache fork and simulating some transactions locally and would like to extract such data even for reverted transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve it by debugging the failed transaction.

From `ganache-cli`, get the required transaction hash. 
In a new terminal window, run `npx truffle debug <YOUR_TXN_HASH>` 
You can then step over to the next line with `o`, till the point transaction was reverted.

A detailed list of commands is available here: https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-the-truffle-debugger.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think `;` makes more sense, stepping one instruction at a time, and then filtering out any log instructions (I will be doing this programatically). I will try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `ganache-cli` with the verbose flag:

```
--verbose
```

This would log the requests and responses.

Now, after you send your request, you will in the logs the response.
This latter would contain the following information:

```json
{
  "id": 17,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": "...",
  "error": {
    "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
    "code": -32000,
    "data": {
      "...": {
        "error": "revert",
        "program_counter": 2145,
        "return": "0x8baa579f"
      },
      "stack": "o: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.o.fromResults (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:4:297036)\n    at w.processBlock (/app/ganache-core.docker.cli.js:42:106258)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)",
      "name": "o"
    }
  }
}
```

The `return` would contain the revert error.

In this case, it is `0x8baa579f`. To know which `error` is it, you will need to know which encoded function/error signature matches the above.

You can use this [online encoder](https://abi.hashex.org/). First, put your ABI there. Then, compare the encoded output with `0x8baa579f`.

For more details on how the encoding works, checkout this [article](https://medium.com/linum-labs/a-technical-primer-on-using-encoded-function-calls-50e2b9939223).